# In Asp.Net 2.0 Identity as I have only enable a role to log in a aplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

in login enable one role for login.

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

return error if login not are in role.

The some way to do this using the Asp.Net 2.0 Identiy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look up the user before signing them in, and check whether they have the role you're looking for.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

if (user != null)
{
    if(await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "YourApprovedRole"))
    {
        // Sign in
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at first read this tutorial from this website :
http://www.asp.net/identity
then work it and try to code as like as the webpage says then you find your solution . 
Note: plz must install sample data form nuget that help you better understanding.